# Access elements in JSON array

Tags: c#, arrays, json

I use an API which returns JSON. I'm having trouble with accessing elements when they are not in an array.

My JSON looks like this:

[image]

On the JSON of 2, I can access the elements with

```
dataJson.Storingen.Ongepland.Storing.@elementName@
```

However, when I use the JSON of 1, I get the following exception:

```
Additional information: Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty does not contain a definition for Traject
```

Comment: Check your JSON again, It seems the second entry is actually nested within the first entry, hence why it is inaccessible. (Unless I'm going crazy) -- Also shouldn't it be dataJson.Storingen.Gepland.Storing.@elementName@ ?
--
`Feel free to post the original JSON on pastebin and I'll look at it.`

Comment: I made mistake. Number 2 works but 1 doesn't, but I still don't know how to fix it

this is the json where i can't access the elements: http://pastebin.com/NsL2txnx

this is the one where it works http://pastebin.com/eFc1JUWv

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 2):

The structure of second json is different about the first.
In second case, you should use `dataJson.Storingen.Ongepland.Storing[0].@property` to access the property that you want.

But if you want to roll up in your array, just to use a `for`

Answer (score 1):

The two JSONs on that picture are not similar in architecture. The first one has a nested "Storing" object, that has several properties, but in the second case, "Storing" became an array of objects. Is it possible that your object model that you're trying to map to tries to parse this array as a single object?

If so, then I think you need to change the type of "Storing" in your model to an array. You will be able to get the elements then like this:
`dataJson.Storingen.Ongepland.Storing[0].@elementName@`

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I thought maybe I could just share my thoughts on this question number 1 I believe, just in case someone from the future saw this.

1st. Create two classes as such:

```
public Storing Test {get; set;}

public class Storing
{
  public string id {set; get;}
  public string Traject {set; get;}
  public string Periode {set; get;}
}
```

2nd. In the main program, deserialize the JSON and call the object as such

```
 TestCase list = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<TestCase>(*your web API uri*);

 Console.WriteLine ("id:{0}, Traject{1}, Periode{2}", list.Id, list.Traject, list.Periode);
```